# How to increase yarn application parallelism

Tags: pyspark, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

I am trying to run multiple yarn applications on EMR Spark, but I am unable to run more than 5 applications at a time.

I am using the following Configurations for Spark Cluster:

Master = r5.2xlarge

Worker = r5.12xlarge
384 GB RAM
48 Virtual Cores
deploy mode = cluster

JSON

```
{
        "Classification":"spark-defaults",
        "ConfigurationProperties":{
          "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions": "-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+G1SummarizeConcMark -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %p'",
          "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions": "-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+G1SummarizeConcMark -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %p'",
          "spark.scheduler.mode":"FIFO",
          "spark.eventLog.enabled":"true",
          "spark.serializer":"org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer",
          "spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled":"false",
          "spark.executor.heartbeatInterval":"60s",
          "spark.network.timeout": "800s",
          "spark.executor.cores": "5",
          "spark.driver.cores": "5",
          "spark.executor.memory": "37000M",
          "spark.driver.memory": "37000M",
          "spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead": "5000M",
          "spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead": "5000M",
          "spark.executor.instances": "17",
          "spark.default.parallelism": "170",
          "spark.yarn.scheduler.reporterThread.maxFailures": "5",
          "spark.storage.level": "MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER",
          "spark.rdd.compress": "true",
          "spark.shuffle.compress": "true",
          "spark.shuffle.spill.compress": "true"
        }
      }
```

How can I increase the number of parallel running Yarn Applications in EMR Spark?

Comment: How many vcores and how much memory is available?  Can you add the YARN info?

Comment: I think yarn depends on the the remaining resource you have, or the container will be broken.

Comment: I have changed the instance types in order to increase the resources but it didn't increase parallel jobs more than 5

Comment: Could you please post how are you submitting the Job. Are you managing any parameters while submitting the Job

Comment: Submitting job as:

"spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --master yarn --py-files s3://bucket_name/spark_standardization.zip s3://bucket_name/preprocess_driver.py"

No additional parameters are being set in command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the Yarn ui running on the master node of the cluster.  Have all of the CPUs and all of the memory been utilized in the cluster?  Increasing concurrency usually means that each individual application that is running can only use a small portion of the cluster.  Also because you've disabled dynamic executor allocation and set the number of executors to 17 you will likely only be able to run a single spark application at a time.

Comment: As per Yarn UI almost all the resources were occupied with first 5 jobs, I tried to reduce executor memory on same cluster and it allowed to run more jobs in parallel.  I got what I wanted to know. Thanks Andrew